# predict(....,type="prob"), without type="prob" is fine, type="prob" with two classes is fine. but type="prob" with multiple classes is wrong

Tags: r, predict

My code for the `predict` function is as following:

```
predict(Flaw.rf, newdata = newtest[-grep("Product", colnames(newtest))], 
        type="prob")
```

When I get rid of the `type="prob"` there is no problem. And if I change the product to just `2`, there is also no problem. However, when the product is multi-classes and I apply `type="prob"`, there is something wrong. It says `undefined columns selected`

Comment: Help us help you by supplying a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That is, data and code that we can run to  reproduce and, hopefully, fix the error your getting. For starters, should `newtest[-grep("Product",colnames(newtest))]` be `newtest[ , -grep("Product",colnames(newtest))]`? (Although you don't need to remove any columns from your test data in order run it through the `predict` function.)

Comment: I can't reproduce this with

`data(iris);`
`set.seed(111);`
`ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2));`
`iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[ind == 1,]);`
`predict(iris.rf, iris[ind == 2,], type = "prob")`. (With apologies for the crap formatting in here.)

Comment: but I can't paste pictures for the reason of the reputation....

Comment: No need for pictures, just post a reproducible example (data + code that reproduces your error).